# Vetor vazio exibe o resultado final da função

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Estou fazendo testes com array/vetor e, como primeira exibição do vetor deveria ser mostrado vazio, como segunda, viria cheio. Qual o problema, por que ocorre ? e como posso corrigir ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ul>
    <li>Murilo</li>
    <li>Mariana</li>
    <li>Steve</li>
    <li>Mark</li>
    <li>Couve</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lista = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    var vetor = new Array();
    console.log("Vetor sem arquivos");
    console.log(vetor);
    function insertIn(vetor, lista){
        for(var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
            vetor.push(lista[i]);
        }
    }insertIn(vetor, lista);
    function mostraDados(vetor){
        console.log("Vetor com arquivos");
        console.log(vetor);
    }mostraDados(vetor);
</script>
```

Comment: Testei no [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wobimiqoya/edit?html,js,console) e aparentemente deu o resultado esperado. Para você saiu 5 elementos nas duas saídas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim, sairam os 5 elementos ao clicar no array para detalhes

Comment: É porque você está imprimindo a referencia de vetor. Se você mostrar na saida apenas o conteúdo irá aparecer corretamente. console.log(JSON.stringify(vetor));

Comment: Eu testei aqui, e curiosamente, quando vou debuggando, ele funciona certo, mas quando deixo rodar, ele imprime nas duas saídas todos os valores

Comment: @Everson, não uso JSON, mas o que seria essa referência de vetor e como funciona ? saberia me dar uma breve explicação ?

Comment: Exato @ArturoTemplário

Comment: Exato. Perceba que ele mostra o vetor vazio contendo elementos, ou seja, na primeira vez o vetor realmente não possui elementos. Porém, o navegador armazena o endereço de memória do vetor e, posteriormente, quando é inserido os valores, é inserido nesta posição de memória. Como o navegador exibe aquela referência, os valores acabam aparecendo também. (Sim, essa é a resposta, mas comentei porque preciso melhorar o texto e deixá-lo mais claro)

Comment: Referência é um ponteiro para a memória onde está o conteúdo da sua variável. Quando você usa referência, qualquer alteração nela faz, com que onde ela estiver referenciada, o conteudo seja alterado. Pelo que eu vi aqui, o Chrome entende que como você mexeu na referencia ao inserir o conteudo no vetor, o conteudo mostrado recebe o valor da referencia.

Comment: Obrigado gente, agora entendi melhor como funciona :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que isso acontece porque o vetor é uma referência, e assim, os valores são sempre inseridos nessa memória. Vê se esse código te ajuda a entender:

```js
    var lista = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    var vetor = new Array();
    
    document.getElementById('encher_vetor').onclick = function () {    
     insertIn(vetor, lista);
    }
    
    document.getElementById('mostrar_vetor').onclick = function () {    
     mostraDados(vetor);
    } 
    
    document.getElementById('esvaziar_vetor').onclick = function () {    
     vetor = [];
    }    
    
    function insertIn(vetor, lista){
        for(var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
            vetor.push(lista[i]);
        }
    }
    
    function mostraDados(vetor){
        console.log(vetor);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Murilo</li>
    <li>Mariana</li>
    <li>Steve</li>
    <li>Mark</li>
    <li>Couve</li>
</ul>
<br>
<input type="button" id="encher_vetor" value="Clique para preencher o vetor" />
<input type="button" id="mostrar_vetor" value="Clique para mostrar o vetor" />
<input type="button" id="esvaziar_vetor" value="Clique para esvaziar o vetor" />
```

O vetor manipulado é sempre a mesma variável, mesma posição de memória.